# How to add kernel args when compiling linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I followed intructions in [this project](https://github.com/ckuethe/usbarmory/wiki/QEMU-Virtual-Armory), but I couldn't figure out how to add `"console=ttyAMA0,115200 panic=5"` to kernel args.
Anyone knows how to add this kernel args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open defconfig

```
vim ./arch/arm/configs/vexpress_defconfig
```

change this

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE="console=ttyAMA0"
```

to this

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE="console=ttyAMA0,115200 panic=5"
```